# Как в пагинации WordPress вывести переход на первую страницу и на последнюю?

Tags: php, wordpress

Сейчас есть пагинация и она выводит постранично, а так же есть переход на следующую и предыдущую статью, но мне так же надо реализовать переход сразу на последнюю и сразу на первую, как это сделать?
Сейчас код выглядит так

```php
<?php
    global $post, $wp_query;

    $query_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '4',
        'category__not_in' => '7',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ?: 1
        );
?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); $query = new WP_Query($query_args); ?>
<?php if( $query->have_posts()){ while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post(); ?>

   /** Content **/

<?php } /* конец while */ ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = null;
    $wp_query   = $query;
    the_posts_pagination(array(
        'show_all'     => true,
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => __(' Back'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next '),
        'add_fragment' => '',
        'screen_reader_text' => ' ',
        'type'         => 'list',
    ));
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $temp_query; ?>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); // конец if ?>
```

Comment: $query->max_num_pages

Comment: не совсем поняла куда его?

Comment: добавить в массив `the_posts_pagination` параметр `'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages`

Все параметры можно посмотреть [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/function/paginate_links)

Comment: пробовала и параметры читала, не пойму все равно..дописываю предложенный вами кусочек кода и ничего не выводит

Comment: тогда добавьте еще `'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') )`

Comment: Пишу так, но по прежнему выводила как и выводит, только постранично и кнопки следующая/предыдущая..не то что надо(

```php
the_posts_pagination(array(
 'show_all'     => true,
 'prev_next'    => true,
 'prev_text'    => __(' Back'),
 'next_text'    => __('Next '),
 'add_fragment' => '',
 'screen_reader_text' => ' ',
 'type'         => 'list',
 'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
 'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') )
));
```

Comment: У вас не выводится первая и последняя страница в пагинации? Или вы хотите заменить в них текст?

Comment: Смотрите, сейчас у меня есть нумерация страниц и по бокам 2 текста "Back" и "Next", а мне надо еще 2 кнопки по бокам "First" и "Last", то есть, что б была возможность перехода и на предыдущую и следующую страницу, как есть сейчас и переход на самую первую и на самую последнюю страницы. Сейчас вообще ничего про первую и последнюю не выводит